# iOS System keyboard over OpenGL - return key

Tags: ios, opengl-es, keyboard

I've implemented the UIKeyInput protocol on a UIView so I can display and use the keyboard but for some reason I can't customize it.

I'm attempting to change the "return" key by:

```
keyboard = [[KeyboardView alloc] init];

[keyboard setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

It's weird because there are no compile errors and XCode's type ahead basically fills all this in, however, when I run it it crashes with: an "unrecognized selector" at the setReturnKeyType call.

Does this not work?  What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Does your custom `KeyboardView` class actually implement the methods of the [`UITextInputTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) protocol (from which `UIKeyInput` inherits)?

Comment: It does now :) Thanks.